# how to clear old entity after restkit mapping and before save to entity?

Tags: core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

In restkit, at some scenario, I want to clear entity before refresh. I use followed code, it works.

```
[self clearcache]; //clear the entity
[manager getObjectsAtPath:self.path parameters:self.parameters success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    [self finishedLoadingWithItems:[mappingResult array]];
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
}];
```

but now I want to clear cache only after the mapping is finish but before saving new items to entity.
I try clearcache  in followed function, but unfortunately this would also clear new items.

```
[self finishedLoadingWithItems:[mappingResult array]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on when you want to do the purge (after all requests?).

Generally, you want to use the [fetch request block](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html#//api/name/fetchRequestBlocks) feature of RestKit (added to the [object manager](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectManager.html#//api/name/addFetchRequestBlock%3a)), where you specify a fetch request to execute which returns the objects which should be purged. RestKit will run this and delete the resulting objects during the mapping.

Comment: it is seemed the fetch request block can only be added and can not be deleted, thus I need use an additional flag so I can set the flag when I want the block to clear the entity. Is there any instance method to add the fetch request block to only be performed once?

Comment: I write a method addFetchRequestBlockOnce, I think this is a good API. (but my version is only a workaround)

Comment: Usually you would use a predicate on the fetch request. Otherwise you could edit the object manager so you can remove blocks or use different object manager instances. Consider a pull request with your change, or raising an issue on github to discuss the modification.

Answer (score 1):

finally, I write a method of addFetchRequestBlockOnce,  it almost same with addFetchRequestBlock,  but will be removed when it was executed.

```
[manager addFetchRequestBlockOnce:^NSFetchRequest *(NSURL *URL) {
}];
```